# How do i enable hover tooltip to show detail of the events in streamlit-calendar (fullcalender)?

Tags: python, hover, fullcalendar, tooltip, streamlit

i am developing a streamlit dashboard to show events in the calendar. I achieved it, however i want to add a tooltip when hover over the event.  i don't know how and most of the solutions are in js which offcourse i have no idea about it. Could some please help by adding the respective code to mine. I'm using open source streamlit-calendar which was built on top of fullCalendar.

https://pypi.org/project/streamlit-calendar/

```
def calendar_data_event(df):
    result = {
        "title": df['Title'],
        "start": str(df['AssessmentDueDate']),  # Convert timestamp to string
        "end": str(df['AssessmentDueDate']),    # Convert timestamp to string
        "Regulator": df['Regulator'],
        "updatedDB_Date": str(df['updatedDB_Date']),
        "AssessmentDueDate": str(df['AssessmentDueDate']),
        "ApplicationDate": str(df['ApplicationDate']),
        "ImpactRating": df['ImpactRating'],
        "ImpactScore" : df['ImpactScore'],
    }
    return result


calendar_options = {
        "editable": "true",
        "selectable": "true",
        "headerToolbar": {
            "left": "today prev,next",
            "center": "title",
            "right": "dayGridDay,dayGridWeek,dayGridMonth",
        },
        "initialView": "dayGridMonth",
    }


calendar_events = [calendar_data_event(row) for _, row in df.iterrows()]
    
custom_css="""
        .fc-event-past {
            opacity: 0.8;
        }
        .fc-event-time {
            display: none;
        }
        .fc-event-title {
            font-weight: 700;
        }
        .fc-toolbar-title {
            font-size: 2rem;
        }
        
    """

calendar = calendar(events=calendar_events, options=calendar_options,custom_css=custom_css,callbacks = [])                     
st.write(calendar)
```

Comment: We're not a free write-my-code service. If you can't understand anything in JS then you first need to at least try and understand, and make an attempt at it. Then come back here if you're stuck on a specific error or problem, based on your efforts to implement examples you've found online or built yourself.  If you want someone to do it all for you, with no input from you, then please find a site where you can hire people to worrk for you. See also [ask] and the [tour] to learn more about Stackoverflow.

Comment: i made those and been creating dashboard for 3 weeks. so i'm giving my input i'm a python guy and never worked with js before. so i posted. I didn't meant to use this platform as code to write service

Comment: Well then what _do_ you want, then ? Because your question is "please give me the JS code". How is that different from treating us as a code-writing service? Regardless of anything else you've done with your application you haven't given any input about the tooltip feature, which is what you're asking us about